# AVD isn't showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have attempted to simply test hello world to see if AVD is loading correctly and have had no luck having the emulator run.

when attempting the start AVD I do not receive errors and from my knowledge the app is running however no emulator shows up on screen like tutorial suggests.

So i'm using widows 7 professional and running android studio with essentially all addons(not obsolete) downloaded.

```
10:17:38 PM Gradle sync started
10:18:30 PM Gradle sync completed
10:18:32 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
10:18:41 PM Gradle build finished in 11s 28ms
10:23:01 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
10:23:07 PM Gradle build finished in 5s 872ms
10:23:15 PM Session 'app': running
10:30:59 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
10:31:04 PM Gradle build finished in 5s 61ms
10:41:30 PM Session 'app': running
10:56:18 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
10:56:24 PM Gradle build finished in 6s 75ms
10:56:47 PM Session 'app': running
```

Comment: Windows or linux or mac ?
from command line try "android list avd"

Comment: Hey i'm using windows 7 and android studio

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps as it should work.

I know by now you must have figured it out on your eclipse menu bar go to

**In Eclipse, Go to:**

> 1) Window
>
> 2) Customize perspective
>
> 3) Command group availability tab
>
> 4) On the check box android SDK and AVD manager check it
>
> 5) Lastly, click on ok

**In Android Studio, just follow this:**

When you will create an **AVD** into your Android Virtual Device Manager, and if suppose there were some warnings for windows RAM size greater the 768 MB might cause problems in emulator". After making the RAM size 768 MB it worked and started immediately. So in that case just increase your RAM size would be near about 1024 MB or more than that.

**NOTE:**

If you are using AVD into your Android Studio, instead use Genymotion, it gives you quick response and run your application in very short time, it is just used for fast and better performance with many more devices.